# Generator ATS and Neutral Bonding

Tags: electrical

Does this look like the proper layout for the neutral bonding?  Each transfer switch on left has a 200A breaker and becomes my new service disconnect.  Therefore, the neutral bonds should be done there and no where else, correct?

My understanding of the NEC is that since my service disconnect location changes to the ATS boxes, the former main panels become sub panels.  Therefore I then must add a 4th conductor dedicated for grounding the subpanels, and the neutral bonds must be broken in them (to avoid unbalanced neutral amperage from load sharing across the ground during normal operation).

Also, running just 3 wires to generator and having it use the primary service's grounding bond is valid for residential applications like this, right?

[image: wire layout]

Comment: Looks like neutral is bonded in the meter pan, so why would you also bond it in the panels?

Comment: Without the bonds inside ATS I would be left with no actual connection to ground for any of the metal conduit and metal boxes, no?

Comment: Does the transfer switch switch the grounded (neutral), or just the ungrounded (hot) conductors?

Comment: @Tester101 the neutrals are unswitched

Comment: @Tester101 I was using these are references  

[link](http://ecmweb.com/site-files/ecmweb.com/files/archive/ecmweb.com/mag/503ecm17fig2.jpg)

http://ecmweb.com/mag/503ecm17fig1.jpg

Comment: Generators and automatic transfer switches always confuse me. Maybe @speedypetey can chime in.